# How to use a method reference inside an Optional.map()

Tags: java, methods, java-8, reference, option-type

I have a Optional.

```
Optional<AssetEvent> latestEvent = ...
```

I want to a add a field from inside the Event to a List if Present.

```
latestEvent.map(event -> event.getTimestamp()).ifPresent(latestList::add);
```

My IDE (Intelij) shows me "Lambda can be replaced with method reference" on `event.getTimestamp()`

refactoring to

```
latestEvent.map(this::getTimestamp).ifPresent(latestList::add);
```

gives me an Error because `this` will refer to the surrounding Object in what the code is executed. How can I refer to the method of the Object inside the Optional `latestEvent`

Comment: This is probably a bug - IntelliJ is generating the wrong method reference here.

Comment: @MTCoster InteliJ is not refactoring atomatically. It was me.

Comment: But doesn’t IntelliJ offer to do the suggested refactoring for you? All other IDEs do offer such an action.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the class name. For example:

```
latestEvent.map(AssetEvent::getTimestamp).ifPresent(latestList::add);
```

Assuming `AssetEvent` is the name of the class having the `getTimestamp` method.